# Python imutils: Illegal instruction

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, imutils

I have a python3 script on my computer that I can run with `python3 motion_detection.py` and that works, I tried to use it on my Raspberry and something fails with message `Illegal instruction`. The line that throws this error is: `frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=500)`

Here is the minimalist sample of code:

```
import imutils
import cv2
frame = cv2.imread('test.jpg')
frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=500)
```

I'm sure that frame is not None because I tried to save it and it worked.
I'm a bit confused because there is no more explaination that `Illegal instruction`
I checked the version of imutils that is the same on my computer that on the Raspberry (0.4.6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the line `frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=500)` to  `frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=500, inter=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)`.  Does that work?

It seems to be a problem with the imutils implementation of resize with *certain interpolation methods*.  The default interpolation method, specified as `INTER_LINEAR`, causes the `Illegal instruction` error on the RPi Zero.  But if you override the default to a non-problematic interpolation method, it may work!  I tested each of the options and found each of the following interpolation methods to run successfully on my RPi Zero : `INTER_NEAREST, INTER_CUBIC, INTER_LANCZOS4`.

Let me know if this works for you.  I wish I had more details on the *why*, but have so far poked around the imutils source code to no avail.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about this question on stackoverflow, your answer is the right answer, Check at this issue I created on the github: https://github.com/jrosebr1/imutils/issues/76
Thanks for taking the time to help me